# Twilio Delete Silently Failing

Tags: node.js, twilio

I'm trying to delete an SMS on Twilio.

```
client.messages(message.sid).delete(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Message deletion error: " + err.status + " -- " + err.message);
    } else {
      console.log("Deleted Message SID " + message.sid + " successfully.");
    }
```

On the [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message) it says that a successful delete should return `HTTP 204 (No Content) with no body.` I'm getting no errors, and my little `Delete message` `console.log` is firing, but the SMS remains in Twilio.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Megan from Twilio here.

The code you have pasted above would not run from slight formatting errors. Here's my complete file which worked, though when I tried it on two different Message Sids, one did not disappear from Twilio.com right away but it was gone when I checked just now. Maybe you were suffering the same issue?

[Assuming you have the Node helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install):

```
var accountSid = 'MYACCOUNTSID';
var authToken = "MYAUTHTOKEN";
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages("MESSAGESID").delete(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Message deletion error: " + err.status + " -- " + err.message);
    } else {
      console.log("Deleted Message SID: successfully.");
    }
});
```

Let me know how it works out.